# How to properly use NHibernate By Code to get the next Sequence in Oracle?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following:

```
  Id(x => x.ID, m =>
                                {
                                    m.Column("IDUSER");
                                    m.Generator(Generators.Sequence);
                                });
```

But how do I specify the sequence name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use:

```
m.Generator(Generators.Sequence,g=>g.Params(new {sequence="seq_name" }));
```

Comment: I took a look at nHibernate source code and found something weird: 

      public class SequenceGeneratorDef : IGeneratorDef
    {
        #region Implementation of IGeneratorDef

        public string Class
        {
            get { return "sequence"; }
        }

        public object Params { get { return null; } }

        public System.Type DefaultReturnType
        {
            get { return typeof(int); }
        }

        public bool SupportedAsCollectionElementId
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
        #endregion
    }

Comment: The ` public object Params { get { return null; } }` seems to make some mess, no?!
Even so I'll give a try to what you said. Thank you

Comment: @RuiLima did you try the proposed solution ?

Comment: It works! In a priori attempt with that method I failed to get the real ID because the table had a OnInsert Trigger in which the ID was being setted from the sequence.  But now I see it's OK! Thank You!!!