# Nhibernate Mapping by Code conventions to Postgres Sequence

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, npgsql

I´m using PostGres 8.3 and have NHibernate working fine with database...
I´m creating a Conventions file and I´m having problem to configure the Primary key sequence... All my tables have a primary key called ID, so I did that :

```
...
mapper.BeforeMapClass += (modelInspector, type, classCustomizer) => {
            classCustomizer.Id(c => c.Column("ID"));
            classCustomizer.Id(c => c.Generator(Generators.Sequence));
};
```

When I try to Save a instance, I got that error:

**ERROR: 42P01: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist**

How Can I create a convention to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [How to properly use NHibernate By Code to get the next Sequence in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503771/how-to-properly-use-nhibernate-by-code-to-get-the-next-sequence-in-oracle)

```
Id(u => u.Id, map =>
            {
                map.Column("id");
                map.Generator(Generators.Sequence,
                              gmap => gmap.Params(new {sequence = "seq_name"}));
            });
```